# matrix multiplication excel vba for data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in excel VBA and would like to ask questions. I have a Sales Data with header. 26 row and 12 column.

Below is my dummy data:

[Dummy Data](http://www.filedropper.com/book1_8)

I would like to create buttons to change currency. for example clicking EUR will change the data into EURO and then click USD will change the data to USD.

This is my code for one of the button:

```
Sub Change_to_EUR()Dim BM_Store_Sales_EUR As Variant
Dim BM_Store_Sales_IDR
BM_Store_Sales_EUR = Sheet3.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(26, 13)).Value
BM_Store_Sales_IDR = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(BM_Store_Sales_EUR, "$O$1")
MsgBox BM_Store_Sales_EUR
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not create a validation list that would be connected to a table containing col1:currency name, col2: exchange rate? You could then call the FX with a VLOOKUP...

Comment: I don't think it is necessary for now, since I only work with 2 currencies. But your comment does give me some inspiration. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (no matrices needed)

Calling `Change_Currency` with a TRUE argument multiples your range with the exchange rate in `O1`, calling it with FALSE (or leaving it blank) divides

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Call Change_Currency(True)
End Sub

Sub Button2_Click()
Call Change_Currency
End Sub
```

*code*

```
Sub Change_Currency(Optional bEuro As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Set ws = Sheets(1)
Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.[b2], ws.[m26])
ws.[o1].Copy

If bEuro Then
    rng1.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlDivide
Else
    rng1.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlMultiply
End If

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this give me more idea. However with this solution if the user click the Button twice, the number will be multiplied/Divided twice, which could be confusing.